# Spark Thrift Server force metadata refresh

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, thrift

I'm using spark to create a table in the hive metastore, then connect with MSSQL to the Spark Thrift server to interrogate that table.
The table is created with:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("TableName")
```

The problem is that every time, after I overwrite the table (it's a daily job) when I connect with MSSQL I get an error. If I restart the Thrift Server it works OK but I want to automate this and restarting the server every time seems a bit extreme.

The most likely culprit is the Thrift cached metadata which is no longer valid after the table overwrite. **How can I force Thrift to refresh the metadata after I overwrite the table, before it's accessed by any of the clients?**

I can settle for a solution for MSSQL but there are other "clients" to the table, not just MSSQL. If I can force the metadata refresh from spark (or linux terminal), after I finish the overwrite, rather than ask each client to run a refresh command before it requests the data, I would prefer that.

Note:

```
spark.catalog.refreshTable("TableName")
```

Does not work for all clients, just for Spark

```
SQL REFRESH TABLE `TableName`;
```

Works for Qlick but again, if I ask each client to refresh it might mean extra work for Thrift and mistakes can happen (such as a dev forgetting to add the refresh).

Comment: What is your thrift metastore db ? try to see if you face same problem with external/local db(for metastore) as well.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm bit lost by your comment. I'm using a Cloudera cluster. The db is "default" not sure how I can change the db where Spark saves the tables.

Comment: You might given some database while installing components. You might get some clue about meta store database under thrift configurations in cloudera manager.